# How to add video to html using flash player

Tags: html, flash, video, flowplayer, flash-video

I want to add video which is of format (mp4) to my page using flash player (not html5). I have tried this using Flowplayer but I am not able to do this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="flowplayer is-splash"
            data-engine="flash"
            data-swf="../dist/flowplayer.swf">
            <video src="http://d32wqyuo10o653.cloudfront.net/Extremists.m4v" preload="none"></video>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain this? I searched a lot experimented a lot but didn't get results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working from me!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="http://d32wqyuo10o653.cloudfront.net/Extremists.m4v" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only use the [flowplayer flash version](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/installation/index.html), you can do something like this  :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://d32wqyuo10o653.cloudfront.net/Extremists.m4v" class="player" style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;margin:10px auto" id="player"></a>
    <script>
        flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see this code working on codebeautify.org [here](http://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/3efa02).

Hope that can help.